# What is the use of ExampleInstrumentedTest.java and ExampleUnitTest.java in android?

Tags: android

What exactly is the use of these classes and what will be the effect if I remove them?

Will it create any issue while publishing the app on play store?

Comment: just example of test code,it won't pack into release version

Comment: Just ignore them, they won't do anything. But I recommend reading a bit about unit tests... they are there for a good reason. Testable code and unit tests are one of the fundamentals of creating stable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These classes are examples of instrumented and unit tests. You can keep them or you can remove them: when you build your release version, these source sets won't be included in your app.